# Get information about a page using facebook4j

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Is there a possibility to get the `String` of the page's information in the about section?
An Example: https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers
Here is the info: "Build, grow, and monetize your app with Facebook. https://developers.facebook.com/"

I found out that the Facebook graph api supports this by the `Field` `about` on a [`Page`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page).

Thanks for help in advance!

Best regards,
Dominic

Comment: Seems like the about field on the page object is what you want? You can read about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. As the topic signalize I want to get it with the Facebook4J Java library

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: I got the `Page` object. Although I cannot find any functionality which can give me the desired `Field`. I took a look in the [documentation](http://facebook4j.org/javadoc/index.html) and tried all possible methods. I don't know what `getCover()`do. It returns always `null`

Comment: Looks like Facebook4j don't have all fields. You will need to change Facebook4j or use some other lib. Or sending the request by yourself somehow so you get the raw result back and not a Page object back

Comment: Ok. I was expecting a support for this simple functionality. I am just using the Facebook4j library to not handle own requests including dealing with raw data -,-

Comment: Just add it. Should be a few lines for code

Answer (score 0):

you can below snippet code for getting facebook page information in java :

```
private static final String FacebookURL_PAGES = "me/accounts?fields=access_token,category,id,perms,picture{url},can_post,is_published,cover,fan_count,is_verified,can_checkin,global_brand_page_name,link,country_page_likes,is_always_open,is_community_page,new_like_count,overall_star_rating,name";   

public List<FacebookPageModel> getPages(String accessToken) throws FacebookException, JSONException {

    JSONObject posts = getBatch(accessToken,FacebookURL_PAGES);
    Gson g =new Gson();
    System.out.println(posts);
    JSONArray postsData =  posts.getJSONArray("data");
    System.out.println(g.toJson(postsData));

    return getPageList(postsData);
}

private JSONObject getBatch(String accessToken, String url) throws FacebookException{
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Facebook facebook = getFacebook(accessToken);
    BatchRequests<BatchRequest> batch = new BatchRequests<BatchRequest>();
    batch.add(new BatchRequest(RequestMethod.GET, url));
    List<BatchResponse> results = facebook.executeBatch(batch);
    BatchResponse result2 = results.get(0);

    System.out.println(g.toJson(result2.asJSONObject()));

    return result2.asJSONObject();
}

private Facebook getFacebook(String accessToken){
    if(accessToken == null){
        System.out.println("Access Token null while request for Facebook Instance !");
        return null;
    }

    Facebook facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
    facebook.setOAuthAppId(appId, appSecret);
    facebook.setOAuthPermissions("email,publish_stream, publish_actions");
    facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(accessToken, null));

    return facebook;
}

private List<FacebookPageModel> getPageList(JSONArray pagesData) throws JSONException{
    Gson g = new Gson();
    List<FacebookPageModel> pages = new ArrayList<FacebookPageModel>();
    SimpleDateFormat desiredFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < pagesData.length(); i++) {
        FacebookPageModel obj = new FacebookPageModel();
        JSONObject page = pagesData.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println(g.toJson(page));
        try{
            obj.setAccessToken(page.getString("access_token"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setAccessToken(null);
        }
        try{
            obj.setCategory(page.getString("category"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setCategory(null);
        }
        try{
            obj.setId(page.getString("id"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setId(null);
        }
        try{
            obj.setName(page.getString("name"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setName(null);
        }
        try{
            obj.setCanPost(page.getBoolean("can_post"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setCanPost(false);
        }
        try{
            JSONObject picture = page.getJSONObject("picture");
            JSONObject pictureData = picture.getJSONObject("data");
            obj.setPageProfilePic(pictureData.getString("url"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setCanPost(false);
        }
        try{
            obj.setPublished(page.getBoolean("is_published"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setPublished(false);
        }
        try{
            obj.setFanCount(page.getLong("fan_count"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setFanCount(0L);
        }
        try{
            obj.setVerified(page.getBoolean("is_verified"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setVerified(false);
        }
        try{
            obj.setCanCheckin(page.getBoolean("can_checkin"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setCanCheckin(false);
        }
        try{
            obj.setGlobalBranPageName(page.getString("global_brand_page_name"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setGlobalBranPageName(null);
        }
        try{
            obj.setPageLink(page.getString("link"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setPageLink(null);
        }
        try{
            obj.setNewLikeCount(page.getLong("new_like_count"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setNewLikeCount(0L);
        }
        try{
            obj.setOverallStarRating(page.getLong("overall_star_rating"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setOverallStarRating(0L);
        }
        try{
            obj.setOverallStarRating(page.getLong("overall_star_rating"));
        }catch(Exception ee){
            obj.setOverallStarRating(0L);
        }

        pages.add(obj);
    }
    System.out.println(g.toJson(pages));
    return pages;
}

public class FacebookPageModel {

//access_token
private String accessToken;
//name
private String name;
//id
private String id;
//category
private String category;
// can_post
private boolean canPost;

private String pageProfilePic;
// is_published
private boolean isPublished;
// fan_count
private long fanCount;
// is_verified
private boolean isVerified;
// can_checkin
private boolean canCheckin;
// global_brand_page_name
private String globalBranPageName;
// link
private String pageLink;
// new_like_count
private long newLikeCount;
// overall_star_rating
private long overallStarRating;

public boolean isCanPost() {
    return canPost;
}
public void setCanPost(boolean canPost) {
    this.canPost = canPost;
}
public String getPageProfilePic() {
    return pageProfilePic;
}
public void setPageProfilePic(String pageProfilePic) {
    this.pageProfilePic = pageProfilePic;
}
public String getAccessToken() {
    return accessToken;
}
public void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}
public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}
public boolean isPublished() {
    return isPublished;
}
public void setPublished(boolean isPublished) {
    this.isPublished = isPublished;
}
public long getFanCount() {
    return fanCount;
}
public void setFanCount(long fanCount) {
    this.fanCount = fanCount;
}
public boolean isVerified() {
    return isVerified;
}
public void setVerified(boolean isVerified) {
    this.isVerified = isVerified;
}
public boolean isCanCheckin() {
    return canCheckin;
}
public void setCanCheckin(boolean canCheckin) {
    this.canCheckin = canCheckin;
}
public String getGlobalBranPageName() {
    return globalBranPageName;
}
public void setGlobalBranPageName(String globalBranPageName) {
    this.globalBranPageName = globalBranPageName;
}
public String getPageLink() {
    return pageLink;
}
public void setPageLink(String pageLink) {
    this.pageLink = pageLink;
}
public long getNewLikeCount() {
    return newLikeCount;
}
public void setNewLikeCount(long newLikeCount) {
    this.newLikeCount = newLikeCount;
}
public long getOverallStarRating() {
    return overallStarRating;
}
public void setOverallStarRating(long overallStarRating) {
    this.overallStarRating = overallStarRating;
}
}
```